# Vim is echoing a lot of variables when launching

Tags: vim

When I launch `vim` it echoes a lot of variables (from my .vimrc I think) to the shell, before asking to continue. Why is this happening and what can I do to stop it?

Here's an example:

```
ycm_cache_omnifunc    #0
oceanic_next_terminal_bold #1
ycm_seed_identifiers_with_syntax #1
vundle#lazy_load      #0
vundle#updated_bundles []
terminal_color_background  #1b2b34
terminal_color_12      #6699cc
vundle#bundle_dir      /home/username/.vim/bundle
syntax_on             #1
did_load_filetypes    #1
ycm_confirm_extra_conf #0

...

v:errmsg               E216: No such group or event: filetypedetect *
v:beval_lnum          #0
v:mouse_lnum          #0
v:completed_item      {}
v:t_dict              #4
v:false                v:false
v:beval_bufnr         #0
v:shell_error         #0
v:testing             #0
v:lc_time              en_US.UTF-8
v:searchforward       #1
v:event               {}
v:mouse_col           #0
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

It then launches fine.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003 and maybe include your vimrc...

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. I used `vim --noplugin -D` to iterate through the lines of the vimrc and I found out that I had accidentally added a line with `let` on it's own that I'd forgotten about. Thanks again!

Comment: You might want to check out the [Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) for questions on Vim!